# Rewrite SQL subquery to JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to remove the subquery from this SQL? I need to order by the "match against" score, but obviously can't order by the alias.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT b.shortDesc,
          b.img,
          sm.uri,
          match(`bodyCopy`, `shortDesc`) against ('Storage' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION) AS score
   FROM `blog` b
   JOIN `sitemap` sm ON sm.id = b.pageId
   WHERE 'Active' IN (b.status, sm.status)
  ) t1
WHERE score > 0
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: At a glance, using a HAVING clause will probably work. I'd need a dump of your schema to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get rid of the subquery:

```
SELECT b.shortDesc,
       b.img,
       sm.uri,
       match(`bodyCopy`, `shortDesc`) against ('Storage' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION) AS score
FROM `blog` b
JOIN `sitemap` sm ON sm.id = b.pageId
WHERE 'Active' IN (b.status, sm.status)
HAVING score > 0
ORDER BY score DESC
```

The value of `score` is not known before the results are computed. It means it can't be used in the `WHERE` clause. Instead, it can be used in `HAVING`. `ORDER` being applied last, it is possible to use `score` here.

Documentation: [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) (also for `HAVING` and `ORDER`)

Comment: So "score" can be in HAVING and ORDER BY, but not WHERE?

Comment: Thanks. I'm still an SQL noob after all these years. :)

Comment: +1, but note that this use of the `HAVING` clause is a MySQL extension that does not exist with other database languages.

Comment: Thanks @BellevueBob. If I wasn't using MySQL, which I happen to be, how would you get around using score in the where clause?

Comment: @keyboardSmasher It really depends on the specific database; some allow references to aliases and others do not.  Some only allow a `HAVING` clause if a `GROUP BY` clause exists.  Note that all databases have their own implementations so always refer to the documentation for the exact version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
SELECT b.shortDesc,
      b.img,
      sm.uri,
      match(`bodyCopy`, `shortDesc`) against ('Storage' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH   
      QUERY EXPANSION) AS score
      FROM `blog` b
     JOIN `sitemap` sm ON sm.id = b.pageId
     WHERE 'Active' IN (b.status, sm.status) and score > 0  
    ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer fails. That's the reason for me creating the subquery: Unknown column 'score' in 'where clause'